# Creating function arguments from a named list (with an application to stats4::mle)

Tags: r

I should start by saying what I'm trying to do: I want to use the mle function without having to re-write my log likelihood function each time I want to try a different model specification. Because mle is expecting a named list of starting values, you apparently cannot just write the log-likelihood function as taking a vector of parameters. A simple example:

Suppose I want to fit a linear regression model via maximum likelihood and at first, I'm ignoring one of my predictors:

```
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(x1 = runif(n), x2 = runif(n), y = runif(n))
Y <- df$y
X <- model.matrix(lm(y ~ x1, data = df))

# define log-likelihood function 
ll <- function(beta0, beta1, sigma){
  beta = matrix(NA, nrow=2, ncol=1)
  beta[,1] = c(beta0, beta1)
  -sum(log(dnorm(Y - X %*% beta, 0, sigma)))
}
library(stats4)
mle(ll, start = list(beta0=.1, beta1=.2, sigma=1)
```

Now, if I want to fit a different model, say:

```
m <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)
```

I cannot re-use my log-likelihood function--I'd have to re-write it to have the beta3 parameter. What I'd like to do is something like:

```
ll.flex <- function(theta){
 # theta is a vector that I can use directly 
  ...
}
```

*if* I could then somehow adjust the start argument in mle to account for my now vector-input log-likelihood function, or barring that, have a function that constructs the log-likelihood function at run-time, say by constructing the named list of arguments and then using it to define the function  e.g., something like this:

```
X <- model.matrix(lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df))
arguments <- rep(NA, dim(X)[2])
names(arguments) <- colnames(X)
ll.magic <- function(bring.this.to.life.as.function.arguments(arguments)){...}
```

**Update:**

I ended up writing a helper function that can add an arbitrary number of named arguments x1, x2, x3... to a passed function f.

```
add.arguments <- function(f,n){
  # adds n arguments to a function f; returns that new function 
  t = paste("arg <- alist(",
  paste(sapply(1:n, function(i) paste("x",i, "=",sep="")), collapse=","),
  ")", sep="")
  formals(f) <- eval(parse(text=t))
  f
 }
```

It's ugly, but it got the job done, letting me re-factor my log-likelihood function on the fly.

Comment: can't you just used `fixed(x2=0)`?

Comment: in this particular example, yes, but if you want to be able to try arbitrarily complex specifications (e.g., adding interactions, transforms etc.), this strategy doesn't work.

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you use `mle` to fit parameters, when `lm` already does that for you??

Comment: oh - my real example is a nasty multinomial logit - I just did a linear regression for demonstration purposes. Btw - thank you for the excellent answer.

Comment: @John check the answer by `Ben Bolker`. it is very elegant as it automatically computes the likelihood for you based on the specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `mle2` function from the package `bbmle` which allows you to pass vectors as parameters. Here is some sample code.

```
# REDEFINE LOG LIKELIHOOD
ll2 = function(params){
  beta = matrix(NA, nrow = length(params) - 1, ncol = 1)
  beta[,1] = params[-length(params)] 
  sigma    = params[[length(params)]]
  minusll  = -sum(log(dnorm(Y - X %*% beta, 0, sigma)))
  return(minusll)
}

# REGRESS Y ON X1
X <- model.matrix(lm(y ~ x1, data = df))
mle2(ll2, start = c(beta0 = 0.1, beta1 = 0.2, sigma = 1), 
  vecpar = TRUE, parnames = c('beta0', 'beta1', 'sigma'))

# REGRESS Y ON X1 + X2

X <- model.matrix(lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df))
mle2(ll2, start = c(beta0 = 0.1, beta1 = 0.2, beta2 = 0.1, sigma = 1), 
      vecpar = TRUE, parnames = c('beta0', 'beta1', 'beta2', 'sigma'))
```

This gives you

```
Call:
mle2(minuslogl = ll2, start = c(beta0 = 0.1, beta1 = 0.2, beta2 = 0.1, 
    sigma = 1), vecpar = TRUE, parnames = c("beta0", "beta1", 
    "beta2", "sigma"))

Coefficients:
     beta0      beta1      beta2      sigma 
 0.5526946 -0.2374106  0.1277266  0.2861055
```

Comment: thanks Ramnath.  I was going to say something along those lines but couldn't be bothered/didn't have time to do the examples.

Comment: i thought so, since you were the author of `bbmle`. i had some thoughts on added functionality to `bbmle` with some improvements to the `vignette`. let me know if you want to talk about it sometime.

Comment: @Ramnath shouldn't it be `parnames(ll2) <- c('beta0', 'beta1', 'sigma')` *before* the mle2 call?

Comment: @Andy is right. The `mle2()` call as written in this answer returns `Error in mle2(...): some named arguments in 'start' are not arguments to the specified log-likelihood function`

Answer (score 4):

It might be easier to use `optim` directly; that's what `mle` is using anyway.

```
ll2 <- function(par, X, Y){
  beta <- matrix(c(par[-1]), ncol=1)
  -sum(log(dnorm(Y - X %*% beta, 0, par[1])))
}
getp <- function(X, sigma=1, beta=0.1) {
  p <- c(sigma, rep(beta, ncol(X)))
  names(p) <- c("sigma", paste("beta", 0:(ncol(X)-1), sep=""))
  p
}

set.seed(5)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(x1 = runif(n), x2 = runif(n), y = runif(n))
Y <- df$y
X1 <- model.matrix(y ~ x1, data = df) 
X2 <- model.matrix(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df)
optim(getp(X1), ll2, X=X1, Y=Y)$par
optim(getp(X2), ll2, X=X2, Y=Y)$par
```

With the output of

```
> optim(getp(X1), ll2, X=X1, Y=Y)$par
      sigma       beta0       beta1 
 0.30506139  0.47607747 -0.04478441 
> optim(getp(X2), ll2, X=X2, Y=Y)$par
      sigma       beta0       beta1       beta2 
 0.30114079  0.39452726 -0.06418481  0.17950760
```

Comment: nice one. but the reason people prefer to use `mle` is that in addition to the parameter estimates it returns a ton-load of useful information like `standard errors`, `AIC` etc. which are useful. it can be done using `optim`, but would need more code.

Comment: True, though if it weren't for Ben, one would have to choose between using this and writing more code to get the useful information, or writing more code to make all the models.  Thanks for the pointer to bbmle, @Ramnath ; it's new to me.

Comment: I agree. `bbmle` is a beautiful package that solves many of the common `mle` jobs. Another package for distribution fitting that is neat is `fitdistrplus`.

Answer (score 3):

It might not be what you're looking for, but I would do this as follows:

```
mle2(y ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),parameters=list(mu~x1 + x2), data = df,
    start = list(mu = 1,sigma = 1))

mle2(y ~ dnorm(mu,sigma), parameters = list(mu ~ x1), data = df,
    start = list(mu=1,sigma=1))
```

You might be able to adapt this formulation for a multinomial, although `dmultinom` might not work -- you might need to write a `Dmultinom()` that took a matrix of multinomial samples and returned a (log)probability.

Comment: i think it should be `start = list(mu = 1, sigma = 1)`, and `x1, x2` instead of `y1, y1`. moreover, the `data = df` argument needs to be added. i took the liberty of making these edits, but please feel free to roll back as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The R code that Ramnath provided can also be applied to the optim function because
it takes vectors as parameters also.