# Adapt mle2 to use an unnamed parameter vector & addition algurments

Tags: r, optimization, mle

Good evening,

I have a quick question about `mle2()` syntax. I have an `optim()` routine that optimizes a log-Likelihood function of the following form (and this runs thousands of times, so i don't want to change much):

```
ObjFun <- function(p, X, y, ModelFunction, CostFunction)
```

where **p** is a vector of 1-8 parameters, **X** is the input `matrix`, **y** is the response/independent variable vector, **ModelFunction** is a function specifying the shape of a model, and **CostFunction** specifies the cost/loss function the model likelihood should incorporate during the optimization. The code works fine with `optim()` or `maxLik` [maxLik] wit the following code:

```
maxLik(ObjFun, method="NM", start=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
           X=conc, y=y, ModelFunction=Model1, CostFunction=GCost)

constrOptim(init.par, ObjFun, ui = Ui, ci = Ci, method = "Nelder-Mead", 
            control = control1, X=X, y=y,  ModelFunction= get(Model1),
            CostFunction= get(GCost))
##i'm obviously using constrained optimization in my actual problem.
```

But I can't get it to work easily with `mle()` or `mle2()`. I just want to run it in mle2 to compare the likelihood profile with my own profiling function. Before i go digging through the `mle2()` code, does anyone know if it's my unnamed parameter vector or the additional arguments that make the function crash? I thought it was the former, but i am confused because the error it's giving me is:

```
mle2(ObjFun, method="Nelder-Mead"", start=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
           X=X, y=y, ModelFunction=Model1, CostFunction=GCost)
"minuslogl() : argument "ModelFunction" is missing, with no default"
```

and that argument is clearly specified. I couldn't really find any examples with additional parameters in the vignettes.

PS:
I would have just commented on this post as it's obviously related:
[Creating function arguments from a named list (with an application to stats4::mle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572260/creating-function-arguments-from-a-named-list-with-an-application-to-stats4ml)
But I don't have enough points to comment.

UPDATE:
mle2() has options `vecpar` and `parnames` options that should allow one to specify "for compatibility with Optim", according to Ben's vignette. I simplified the objective function (the log-likelihood) to include hard-coded loss and model examples. The result looks like this:

```
mod2 <- mle2(ObjFun2, method="Nelder-Mead", start=list(1,2,3,4,5),
        vecpar=T, parnames=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

However this still doesn't work. I have a hard time troubleshooting it because i don't know how to refer to the parameters inside the objective function after the call from `mle2`. If i include debugging commands such as `print(p[2])` inside the `ObjFun2`, it returns `NULL`. So the parameter is no longer in a vector form. However `print(A)` forces the function to crush. Again, I can't find any working examples of this online, so maybe I'm missing something very simple.

I can't use the `parameters` argument  as Ben suggested in the above link because my models are not linear.

I attempted to look inside the `mle2()` but got stuck on a call to `calc_mle2_function()`.

Comment: mle2() has options